# How would I find the POST parameters of a website using google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, post

I've been searching for an answer to this question on stackoverflow. None of them really gave me what I wanted.

How would I find the POST parameters of a website?

Comment: Download Firebug for google chrome.Open it and send the post request, you will get info about post parameters on console tab, or on "Net" tab there in firebug.

Comment: Chrome has a build in network (not-only) console. Same as Firefox and even the Internet Exploader. Most commonly opened by pressing F12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Inspector Tool (press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or right click -> inspector).
2. Click on the "Network" tab.
3. Refresh the page. The inspector shows the list of the resources called. For each resources, the inspector records the http request and the http response.
4. Click on the resource that you want inspect and read the request (click on the headers tab to the left of the resources list). You can see the request headers, the form data and the query string parameters.
   [image]

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer covers this pretty well, but I just wanted to clarify to make sure we answered everything you need, since you mentioned that other questions didn't.

After making a POST request, such as logging in to Yahoo in my example below, in the Network tab you can see the request URL. You can find your POST parameters in the Form Data section, and it's laid out nicely as per below:

[image: Network Request]

Notice, for example, the `username` parameter has value 'myemail@test.com', matching the content in the username form field I submitted. Other parameters are hidden fields for state, timezone, etc.

You can also view this information and some more detail by exporting the HTTP Archive (HAR):

[image: Network Export HAR]

You can open it up in a text editor and view the full data in a JSON format, which can consequently be imported into apps like [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/)

[image: HAR]